# Generalized Cantor set removing the open middle $\alpha_n$-th

Tags: measure-theory

I'm working on some Measure Theory problems and came across this relatively interesting problem (to me, at least.)

Fix a sequence $\{\alpha_j\}_{j=1}^\infty \subset (0,1)$, and consider the generalized Cantor set $C_\alpha$ constructed by starting with $K_0=[0,1]$, and removing open middle $\alpha_1$-th of $K_0$ to produce $K_1$ and so on. Define $C_\alpha=\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty K_j$.

There are 3 problems associated with this:

1. Compute $m(C_\alpha)$.
2. Show that for any $\beta \in [0,1]$, some choice of $\{\alpha_j\}$ results in $m(C_a)=\beta$.
3. Show that $C_\alpha$ is nowhere dense.

For 1., I think the measure would be in the form of $(1-\alpha_1)(1-\alpha_2)(1-\alpha_3)...$ but I'm not sure if that intuition is right, or if that sums up to a 'nicer looking' term.

For 2., I have no idea how to go about this one, and would like some help on this part.

For 3., Since $C_\alpha$ is a countable intersection of closed sets, it should be closed as well. Now since it is closed, $C_\alpha$ is equal to its closure, and remains to show that it has an empty interior. But clearly, the set should have an empty interior, as $C_\alpha$ cannot contain an interval.
Now, I was hoping to use monotonicity to reach a contradiction if $C_\alpha$ is not nowhere dense, but I came to a point where I would need to know $m(C_\alpha)$ to do that, so came to a dead end since I wasn't able to solve 1.

I would greatly appreciated some help on these questions, thank you!

Comment: Here are the constructions of some [fat Cantor sets](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.758.1414&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Comment: @Matematleta thank you for your comment. So was my answer in 1. correct? In addition, any idea how to go about 2., or if 3. is correct as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only issue here is $(2).$ The rest is OK. I think we can do $(2)$ directly, without iteration. Say you want $m(C)=\beta$ and you need to choose $(\alpha_j)_j$ so that $\prod^\infty _{j=1}(1-\alpha_j)=\beta.$ Or equivalently, $\sum^{\infty}_{j=1}\ln (1-\alpha_j)=\ln \beta.$ (Note, if the product makes sense, then so does the sum). We can accomplish this by solving the equations $\ln (1-\alpha_j)=\frac{\ln \beta}{2^{j}},\ $ and if we do this, we get $\alpha_j=1-\exp\left ( \frac{\ln \beta}{2^{j}} \right ).$

Comment: Thank you for you answer! I think I understand both iteration and your example now. With that said, how can I go about solving 3? Indeed, $C_\alpha$ will not contain an interval, but I cannot use the monotonicity argument in the measure of the generalized Cantor set being 0 (as I have an infinite product instead.)

Comment: Suppose $C$ contains an interval $I$. Then,  you can find an integer $k$ s.t. at the $k$th step of the construction, $C_k$ is a union of intervals of diameter $<|I|.$ Since $C=\cap C_k$, that's enough for the contradiction.

Comment: is this the contradiction: Take an interval of an arbitrary length. Now, for each iteration, the length of the intervals must decrease since $\alpha_i<1$. Then there exists some $k$, that the product of $(1-\alpha_i)$ where $1\leq i \leq k$ is less than the interval length. Therefore, the $k$-th iteration cannot contain the interval, creating a contradiction as $C_\alpha$ is the intersection of all iterations. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: thank you for your help!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Your answer to 1) is correct, because at step n the value $(1-\alpha_1)\ldots(1-\alpha_n)$ is clearly the total length of $\cap_{j=1}^n K_j$, and the measure of n intersection of a decreasing sequence of sets is equal to the limit of the measures, i.e. it is the limit of the partial products, i.e. it is the infinite product.

For 2), it's time to explore. Can you produce an infinite product equal to $1/2$? to $1/3$? Can you generalize?

Comment: I see. I'm not sure if I know how to create infinite products for a general number in [0,1)... Also, if my answer to 1) is correct, then how could I go about solving 3? I was hoping that $m(C_\alpha)$ would be 0 to use monotonicity argument, but if it's finite, maybe I can't do that.

Comment: @pilotmath: Do you know how to create infinite _sums_ that converge to a given number?

Comment: I'm afraid that I do not.

Comment: @pilotmath: Do you know how to create a _decreasing seqence_ that converges to a given number? (These are not difficult tasks -- there are infinities of possibilities, and the only real barrier to clear is that you need to choose one of them).

Comment: @Henning Markholm Could I just have a sequence$\{b_n\}$ where for $n>N$ for some $N$, $b_n=x$ where $x$ is the given number?

Comment: @pilotmath: Who is that? No, you would need a _strictly_ decreasing sequence here.

Comment: @HenningMakholm sorry for the typo, I could take $a_n=1/n$ which would decrease to 0, and I could add x to each term, right?

Comment: @pilotmath: Indeed. And then decide that this sequence will be the partial products $(1-\alpha_1)\cdots(1-\alpha_n)$. You may need to drop some terms from the front to make sure they're all less than $1$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I'm sorry but I think I'm a bit lost on that part, how I can decide the sequence will be the partial products...? I'm not sure what you mean with that. Could you possibly write this out in an answer in the hopes of helping me understanding fully? Sorry, I'm rather new to analysis.

Comment: @pilotmath: If you have decided what $(1-\alpha_1)\cdots(1-\alpha_n)$ will be for each $n$, you get a sequence of equations that you can use to find what the each $\alpha_n$ needs to be to make that wish come true.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I'm clearly failing to make that wish come true at the moment. Lol. I don't think I'm understanding you clearly enough to proceed to actually solve part 2.

Comment: @pilotmath: Start from the beginning. If you have selected a $b_1$ and want $(1-\alpha_1)=b_1$, then what must $\alpha_1$ be? Now if you _also_ have a $b_2$ and want $(1-\alpha_1)(1-\alpha_2)=b_2$, then what must $\alpha_2$ be?

Comment: @HenningMakholm so for each $n$, $a_n=1-b_n/b_{n-1}$ right? So do I create a sequence that converges to any $\beta$ and then form infinite product such that each $\alpha_n=1-\beta_n/\beta_{n-1}$, where $\beta_n \to \beta$?